# Can Scrum and Lean principles ruins the life of professionals?

Tags: scrum, methodology

I work with scrum about 2 months and don’t have all the experience I wish, so I would like to hear some inputs about it.

My concern is people never say about drawbacks for the two sides; company and workers. 
I know the benefits of a cross-functional team but which are the drawbacks? What is hidden beside the amazing Eden Garden?

I'm confused because as a company benefits of replaceable people, for the team is good because the opportunity of having knowledge and share experience (besides all teamwork benefit).

Again, I know all the benefits but I want explore the drawbacks just because in the middle there are the ordinary people.
Normally these people dedicate heavily to gain knowledge. They buy books, courses, attending seminar and so on.

In every company when someone knows much more than everyone else, people and managers get desperate wishing or even demanding that these ordinary people share all their knowledge.

And that’s strange.. Because these are communism thoughts and we live in capitalism society and since I was born, everything was so competed and now people say about collaborative.

Can Scrum and Lean principles ruins (or making hard) the professionals' life?

Comment: Can you maybe rephrase your question?  "What are the drawbacks of Scrum" is pretty different from "Can Scrum ruin my life?"

Comment: Companies are not run as a capitalist system.  They compete against one another in a capitalist free market but internally they are almost all run as a centrally managed, planned economy.  E.g. internally they are run very like socialism.

Comment: @Nat: actually most companies are run internally like a Monarchy, sometimes like Feudal Monarchies.

Comment: @kloucks: Yeah, if they were run like socialism, everyone would know your pay because it would be the same as theirs among other things. ;)

Comment: I suggest a better rewording would be ***'What are common ways in which Scrum and Lean can be misapplied that damage company culture?'***

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scrum and Lean, in and of themselves, cannot ruin anybody's life.  Nor can they, alone, make your life.

The culture of your organization will always be a far more dominant factor than the particular product management or development management method in place.  Scrum can be misused.  Lean can indeed make workers feel replaceable and pressured to perform all day, all the time.

On the other hand, both tools (they are just tools) can be used to create high-performing teams where all members value each other and each others' contributions.  Being on a team that delivers consistently good results at high velocity feels great.

You will also find every result in between.  It depends much more on culture than process.

I believe that culture flows from the top.  Therefore, look at how the company leaders treat each other, their subordinates, their vendors, and their customers.  That will tell you much more about what your life will be like than which methodology the company follows.

Comment: Thanks mtnygard, what you said about Culture will definitely organize my arguments.

Comment: Scrum can be mis-used... they are trying it here were we are and it's turning more into a time sheet than a Scrum.  When you put meetings on your scrum and try to justify a certain amount of hours of work a day... it's a time sheet.

Answer (score 5):

I'm only going to address your comments about sharing knowledge reducing your own value. In an ideal team culture, knowledge itself isn't as valued as someone's ability to acquire new knowledge and solve problems they haven't seen before. When I think about the star engineers I have known, it's not because they know this or that, it's because it's obvious they could be on nearly any task, on nearly any team and they would both begin to solve the problem and raise the level of the entire team.

Comment: I still firmly believe in hiring people because they can solve problems, not because they know a thing.

Comment: That's a very nice comment I'm glad you did it. Knowledge itself is a value specially in the information age where the knowledge workers are compared to the industrial workers of the past century (which actually still on the base). Knowledge is considered a tool, nobody can take it from you but what the real value of the popular things? I'm not trying to say that everything must be hidden, but I believe on limits - Lot of people on the Vatican may agree with that. As mtnygard said .. in the end the culture determines the situation.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things I've seen from agile methodologies which I'd put against it when you're weighing it up.

From a developers perspective there are two things:

1) The short sprints often lead to short term decisions - which is as intended but can be frustrating for some developers.  While delivering "just enough" is great for the project, asking a developer to do something that they know that they're going to have to very heavily refactor, if not rewrite, two sprints down the line can be demotivating.

2) Where you've got opinionated developers (and is there any other sort) I've seen conflict over prioritisation.  Adding not only what should be done but how important it is and therefore when it should be done brings on a whole other level of disagreement.  In theory the developers don't have a say here but hard delination never works.

From a management point of view they don't like the uncertainty.  "When's it going to be ready?"  "No idea, when we get to the point you say you're happy".  Essentially for them it's a leap of faith - if they do it once then generally they're sold but getting them to do the first time is hard.

Comment: 1) I have another vision about "short sprints". I work in a scrum team and change to scrum was the best thing we ever did to save the project.

2) The project owner do prioritisations, developers only show the situation. The only conflict that happens is when not experienced developers try share inexperiences or seniors developers fight for the "dream land solution".

We don't have problem about uncertainty. The sprint is shot, the tasks are estimated and we normally overlaps the number of tasks we supposed to do working only 8 hours. It is not a big deal! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Just throwing a few things out there we saw when we put it in - and these were experienced (10 years plus) developers.

When I say there's uncertainty, I mean about the overall project length.  You know how long until a sprint is delivered but you don't know at the beginning how many sprints are needed to "finish" a system, largely because at that point what comprises finished and what comprises the system aren't clear.

Where a system is fully spec-ed management have a (normally false) sense of knowing how long it will take.  It may be false but it's still reassuring for them.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume, that as one commentator suggested, you meant to ask: "*What are the drawbacks of Scrum?*"

I think that the biggest problem with Scrum is that it is easy to understand - but very difficult to implement ***properly***. Scrum, like XP, like most methodologies is **not** built on individual atomic practices, each capable of improving an existing process. 
Scrum requires a shift in the organizational mindset. It requires a shift from ego-centric to communal behavior. The entire organization should focus on bringing the most value, constantly, and do so over perceived self-interest.
For example, a cross-functional team member may be required to do things out of his comfort zone (the flip-side of being able to experiment with new interesting tasks), because it needs to be done by somebody.
Team Leaders and project managers need to relinquish authority when they are called to take on the role of servant-leaders, and when they are asked to *stop* telling team-members which tasks to pick, instead relying on the team to manage itself.
Stakeholders are forced to face the reality that they can't eat the cake, and have it whole, when they are forced to **choose** between having all of the scope they want **or** having it by the date they want it done (this is **always** true, but Scrum is really in-your-face about it).

Most of all, the drawback of Scrum, is its tendency to disillusion beginning practitioners. This comes from people expecting something from it that it can't deliver: **A solution to their problems**!

That's right! Scrum does *not* solve an organizations problems. It highlights them. It is up to the organization to step up to the bat and do something about them. Incidentally, this is done with what I consider to be the single most important ceremony of Scrum - The Retrospective! If you do nothing else in Scrum - do the retrospective:

- Find out what you did well, and continue doing it.
- Find out what you need to improve and do something to improve it.
- Rinse and repeat!

In a presentation by Ken Schwaber to Google on Scrum, he once said that Scrum isn't necessarily good for the organization. It could tell you early on that your project is doomed to fail. If you avoid Scrum, you may have a few more months of ignorant bliss to prepare you for the day you lose your job. Funny, but true. Think on that.

Hope it helps,
Assaf.

Comment: Many thanks, Assaf. That's was a very solid view on the subject.

Comment: Welcome. We aim to please...
:-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in any particular methodology (Agile, Scrum, etc.) but I empathize with your feelings. One of the biggest issues I've seen is that a team that really isn't interested almost unanimously in the methodology will tend to have problems. A few outliers isn't a problem, but if 1/3 or more of the team isn't interested, it becomes a nightmare. Writing good software is important and a company should hire professionals that help them meet that goal, but if the team is forced to meet that objective without finding the experience rewarding the quality will soon drop off.

No, I don't think it will ruin your professional life, but it can be pretty miserable if a company is pig-headed and doesn't realize that they need an environment where their workers are finding rewarding work.

Comment: Andrew, thanks, really thanks! I don't think it will ruin our professional life too. I think I exaggerated a little bit in the question but what mtnygard said helped me organize my arguments as you did too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure of the question because it was kind of hard to follow.

Basically... no? I fail to see how an agile principle could 'ruin a professionals' life'...  if implemented incorrectly it could waste some of their time, meaning a small lack of experience gained. Other than that, if the methodology fits the business and is implemented correctly, then is is a powerful tool that is useful to everybody.

Any methodology only works if the people are competent.

Silly question imo.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to explore the drawbacks and not the benefits. Thanks for your response. I'll update the question as I recommend you get in touch with the lean principles and Toyota system. I usually get satisfied when I know benefits and drawbacks, otherwise makes me blind and fool.

Answer (score 0):

I've certainly seen things packaged as Scrum and Lean make the development process more difficult.  Usually the result of managers picking and choosing the aspects that support their purpose, without buying in to the underlying spirit.  Any process can work if properly applied, and process can fail if applied poorly.

Comment: That's the reason for uncomfortable feelings.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-functionality isn't a means to make people replaceable. It's a means to solve flow bottleneck problems that decrease productivity.

Cross-functionality doesn't mean that everyone can do everyone else's job, it means that people are capable of assisting with the work step that come (immediately) before their work or (immediately) after their work.

A better term for this is "Local Generalization", or "Special Generalization". And again, the goal has nothing to do with making people more removable from the organization. Creating the kid of people who can use Local Generalization to their advantage costs a lot of money in teaching and guidance. Once an organization makes such an investment in a worker, they're even less motivated to remove them. And organizations tend to only make such investments in people that they already want to keep around.

Comment: Hi sbellware. It's been almost two years that I work with scrum. I've witnessed case of "interchangeable" people in means of disposable people. I've I noted some phases: 
1º - scrum started as the best thing in the world - give power to the team. Everybody is happy.
2º Everybody's expectation is aligned. People start to work professionally.
3º As the time goes by most important skills is spread among different people.
4º Company start to cut cost.

I agree it all depends on company's culture as I've seen no coach or scrum evangelist saying such drawn backs for workers.

Comment: In most event I've been. Actually, most people tend to behave like blinded religious. And when you point some good argument, most of them tend do react with good joke (you know, behind the laughs always offending who ask the question in good manner). I like scrum in the end but don't like how people use it.

Comment: Indeed, it's all about culture. After many years on Scrum projects, I turned my attention to Lean a few years ago as it had much more to say about how management and leadership should be expected to operate. If the directors of an organization use human resource shedding as an optimization, we're inevitably left wondering about their competence as managers and leaders in the first place. Then again, if an organization truly transforms itself in a a lean, learning culture, then it might find itself in possession of human resources that no longer fit with the new organization.